# Does anyone know what happened to javaspec.org?

Tags: java, wiki

javaspec.org should contain a java-related wiki; but it seems down... Is this only temporary or is it down 'forever'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain was registered in Jan 2008 through GoDaddy, by "DomainByProxy".

It sounds like the original owners shut it down and let the domain name expired, and then someone else picked it up, and haven't decided what to do with it yet.